# How to make an if statement based on multiple boolean variables contained in a single comma delimited cell

Tags: excel

I have product data in an excel sheet.  The products have a parent/child relationship, so in one column is the parent sku, and in the second column is all the child skus linked to the parent, in a comma delimited format.

I have a second excel sheet with the stock status of all the children (1 = in stock, 2 = out of stock).

I'm trying to figure out a way to say "if ALL the child skus for a given parent sku are out of stock, mark the parent out of stock, if not, mark it in stock".

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

I know I can use text to columns to separate the child skus into different columns, but then I'm left with rows of varying lengths, since the number of child skus tied to each parent varies.  I thought about trying to apply vlookup or hlookup or match and index, but for the life of me I can't think of a practical way to accomplish this.  In reality my data set is thousands of rows long and there are anywhere from 2 to 30 child skus associated with each parent sku.

FYI, I'm pretty versed at formula manipulation in Excel, but I don't know much of anything about using macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate the comma delimited text and sum all the child status.  If >0 it returns in stock otherwise out of stock

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)))),"In Stock","Not Instock")
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing!  Thank you!  We actually use 2 to represent out of stock, not 0.  Can this formula be adapted to account for that?  Otherwise I can do a find/replace, that's fine.

Comment: It could but it would be a lot more work.  It would be easier to use 0,1

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I can convert it to 0, 1 pretty easily.  Is there anyway to adapt this to say "if ANY child skus are out of stock, make the parent out" instead of "if ALL.."?

Comment: That is a new question, please create a new post.

Comment: It's not letting me create it separately because it's saying it looks like a duplicate of this one :(

Comment: use a different title and verbiage.  link back to this question and explain what you have tried to modify the formula I gave to your needs and where it is lacking.  If you just copy paste it will not let you and it would be rightfully closed as a dup.